# Abstract class accessing the implemented type through a templated virtual function?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I was wondering if there could be any way to write a template function in an abstract class, and have it (the template function) automatically instantiated with the type of the derived class?

So you have a class that looks something like this

```
class A
{
  virtual template < typename T>
  void vtfunc(void)
};
class B : public A
{
  /// No declared members pertaining to this example
}
```

Then, whenever a class derived from A is declared, it compiles "vtfunc" with itself as the template parameter T.
Then, calling vtfunc() through an interface of A calls the isntance of that function compiled for its derived class B.

Is there any way of doing this, or writing something fiddley that have this effect?

Obviously I am aware that the template parameter could only affect the internals of the class, and not the return type and parameters - they would need to be the same because of the way polymorphism works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure what you’re after but one common pattern is the so-called [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); here, the base class itself is the template, not its member functions. In other words:

```
template <typename T>
class A 
{ 
    virtual void vtfunc(void) 
};

class B : public A<B>
{
    …
};
```

Comment: Add another superclass of `A` for true polymorphism. :)

Comment: Woop! Awesome answer thanks, I didn't actually think this would be possible lol >< Although as Xeo says, I need to make one more class above A so this polymorphism can actually be used.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a non-member function instead.